# is it possible to use the "alarm" function in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, alarm, launcher

i would like to know if is it possible to use the alarm of the device by a launcher in WP7 (basically with a timespan for i.e)
tjx all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API in the current framework that enables access to the Alarms application.

Comment: i knew that but i wasnt sure and unfortunately we can run an application under the lock screen.. thx Derek for ur help